# Export data from PowerBI report table to CSV in OneDrive using Power Automate

Tags: powerbi, dax, power-automate

I am trying to export data from powerBI data set to Csv using power automate but I am hitting export limitation in powerBI.
I have 27 columns and more than 10000000k rows.

```
Dataset in powerbi :  

    example :
    Name class number
    Ram    5    300
    shyam  6    700
```

I am running Dax Query In Power Automate and converting it to csv. using below flow.

[image]

But when I am checking in Json response from `Run a query against dataset`  I am seeing a limitation error as.

[image]

I found one youtube video to loop into dataset :
Link : https://youtu.be/fbeMw9jtJB4?si=kUirHeeEULWE6DIz
Which might help me to overcome data export limit but in data source she has index column. which she is utilizing filter data and the export it in a while loop.

But In my case I don't have index column in data source nor i have access to manipulate datasource.

I tried multiple things but I am stuck here and unable to export all data into one csv. can someone please guide me.